# Max of 2 columns per suggestion?

Tags: android, android-searchmanager

Can each search suggestion can display only a max of two columns?  The SearchableDictionary sample in the Android SDK shows the word (SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1) and its definition (SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_2) in response to a user typing in the search bar.  Is it possible to add, say, a third line underneath?  None of the other SUGGEST_COLUMN_* seem appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering this as [I got confirmation](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/android-tutorial-adding-suggestions-to-search/#comment-5692) from grokkingandroid.com that there's a max of 2 columns allowed for a suggestion.  Link is: